# SSIS: Can I edit my recordset as I loop through it using the foreach statement?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I am using SSIS to make a series of complicated data exports, and I've hit a roadblock.  I've populated a package variable with a recordset.  I'd like to use a foreach loop to iterate through each row in the recordset.  I'd like to update one of the columns in each row based on some calculations which I've done inside a script task.

Is this possible?  I know in C# the foreach collection is immutable, but I don't know if SSIS works the same way.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any good examples of using the for loop construct instead, which might be a potential solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put data into a recordset it's stored in an object variable. You can use the Foreach Loop Container - and loop the object variable. You then create some variables to hold each column for the row - and you then have a row-by-row ability to do whatever you please, be it a data flow task, sql statement, script task (c#) or anything else.

See http://www.sqlis.com/post/Shredding-a-Recordset.aspx for an illustrated example of how to do this and send an email for every row.

Comment: I can get this far, but want to update the data in the original recordset, not just edit the columns.  Still testing to see if the original recordset can be modified within a foreach loop.

Comment: May i ask what the reason for doing this is, as the recordset is an in-memory destination that doesn't get stored anywhere. If you are going to store it somewhere, just do your calculation while you store it wherever.

Comment: That is a good point.  By storing the record in memory and then saving it to a destination later, I am duplicating work.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh and by the way i don't think you can in any way alter the values in the recordset, as the foreachloop extracts this into other variables, with no means of accessing the parent recordset (as far as i know, maybe some c#-whackers will know if it can be done.)